# Backspace for target in nuspec file

Tags: nuget, backspace, nuspec

If I need to have backspace for target target in nuspecc file it replace backspace to %20 in package.
Example:

```
<file src="my folder\script.js" target="test\my folder" />
```

in nuspec file 
after packing causing "test\my%20folder" path in generated package. Any ideas how to deal with that?